# Passing truststore to javaws as command line argument

Tags: java-web-start, truststore

We have a java webstart application which is hosted a web server. The signer of the SSL certificate in the web server is not in the cacerts of the JRE, by default. Thus when we run

`javaws https://blablah/our.jnlp`

we get a Security Warning dialog saying the connection the website is untrusted. Is it possible to pass a custom truststore that contains the singer certificate to the javaws process? to avoid the warning?

I was hoping following would work

`javaws -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path_to_custom_trusstore>  https://blablah/our.jnlp`

where `custom_trusstore` contains the signer certificate.

This does not seem to work. Warning still shows.

I know alternatively we can add the signer certificate from the Java Control Panel, but is there any other way?

Comment: An alternative solution is to set user configuration at runtime, like this

`javaws -userConfig deployment.user.security.trusted.cacerts <path_to_custom_trusstore>`

and then run the application, followed by unsetting the property.

This isn't a proper solution to my problem, but just found that so commenting it

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add the password?

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=storePassword
```